# Rails - allows user to do some actions only few times within certain timeframe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, ruby-on-rails-5, backend

I have Rails api, and I use it to upload photos from the mobile app. Is there a way to set something like a timer from Rails back-end to let say allow one user only upload twice in an hour and/or another user twice in a day? I am a little puzzled with logic of how it can work from the back-end since I don't wanna do it from the front-end. Any advice is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You should take 2 fields in table something like `upload_count:integer`  and `last_uploaded_at:datetime`. update the values of 2 fields according user upload photos, Before upload check the last_uploaded time and upload_count, if it is false than show error, for renew it after 24 hours you can use cron jobs, please check `gem whenever` for more information

Comment: you do not need `last_uploaded_at` field. there is already a field for that in every `Model` table called `updated_at`

Comment: Actually just the `created_at` field is sufficient. Using a cron tab as suggested by @Vishal is a very overcomplicated solution to a simple problem that can be handled with SQL.

Comment: the `updated_at` will everytime update if we change any field of Model, we need to update `last_uploaded_at` only when any file is upload. not for every field

Comment: @max , do you know how the database is handled in his system ?

Comment: No - but assuming there is a pretty standard setup with timestamps you can get the last uploaded by just ordering by creation time. Its much cheaper than a bunch of update queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple. Just check how many records the user has created in the alloted time frame. Lets say you have the following associations:

```
class User
  has_many :photos
end

class Photo
  belongs_to :user
end
```

And a `current_user` method that returns the authenticated user.

To query based on a time frame you use a [range](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Range.html):

```
def create
  @photo = current_user.photos.new(photo_params)

  unless current_user.photos.where(created_at: (1.hour.ago..Time.now)).count <= 2
    @photo.errors.add(:base, 'You have reached the upload limit')
  end

  # ...
end
```

Later when you refactor you can move this into the model as a [custom validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-validators).

Comment: You have not provided any details on what the heuristics of who gets what upload limit but the general approach is the same.